# Typescript cannot infer value from map based on generic key type

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I am trying to refactor an existing feature of my app and had this typescript issue.

It looks like TS cannot pick up the right type when passing the generic type through the nested functions.

```
enum App {
  AppOne = 'app-one',
  AppTwo = 'app-two',
}

const mockedData = {
  [App.AppOne]: {
    id: '1',
    name: 'app-one',
    age: '18'
  },
  [App.AppTwo]: {
    id: '2',
    name: 'app-two',
    gender: 'male'
  }
} as const

const condition: string = 'good'

function getDataPerApp(app: App): { entries: string[] } {
  const entries: string[] = []

   if (app === App.AppOne) {

  // `prepareData` works totally fine with correct typings based on the if statement conditions
  /* function prepareData<App.AppOne>(app: App.AppOne, data: {
    readonly id: "1";
    readonly name: "app-one";
    readonly age: 18;
    }, entries: string[], condition: string): string[]*/

      const res = prepareData(app, mockedData[app], entries, condition)
      return { entries: res }
   } else if (app === App.AppTwo) {
      const res = prepareData(app, mockedData[app], entries, condition)
      return { entries: res }
   } else {
     return {
      entries: ['unknown data']
     }
   }

   return { entries }
}

function prepareData<T extends App>(app: T, data: typeof mockedData[T], entries: string[], condition: string): string[] {
   if ( condition === 'good') {

     // `finalData` is not able to infer the right typing
     // app: T extends App
     // data is just all the possible types

     // If I directly call this `finalData` in the `getDataPerApp` function above, it infers the     // types correctly

     const res = finalData<T>(app, data)
     entries.push(res)
   } else if ( condition === 'bad') {
    const res = finalData<T>(app, data)
    entries.push(res, 'this is bad')
   } else {
      return entries
   } 

   return entries
}

function finalData<T extends App>(app: T, data: typeof mockedData[T]): string  {

  if (app === App.AppOne) {

   /* ERROR: Property 'age' does not exist on type '{ readonly id: "1"; readonly name: "app-one"; readonly age: 18; } | { readonly id: "2"; readonly name: "app-two"; readonly gender: "male"; }'.
  Property 'age' does not exist on type '{ readonly id: "2"; readonly name: "app-two"; readonly gender: "male"; }'. */

    return data.age  
  } else if (app === App.AppTwo) {
    return data.gender
  } else {
    return 'no'
  }
}
```

[ts playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYOwrgtgBAggDnKBvAsAKCrBB5EwoC8UA5AIYIC0A9nsQDTqbxwAqA7lYSeXBQC4d66AL7p0AYxoBnPlAhVxAa2AATACKk+pLqgxQA2swB0zXMAC6ALmSNMUAJYrrxAIxC9mEKQjBnParQMHlCkAOa+UC4AHLbCQZiGCCYI7FRWNsGOzgBM7nZQXj5+lAJUeXbhICrAAE7OEKQANsDEsSIhUlCSIDJiaN0yXTQq9nz2NNYyNfYgoVzEoVRUKq1o6ABmYCDiYzRQ4XwaWgAKtcwAFDzWzACU1khQoHzTwFKTzzOh+uZQwhmYA1kTxebygU0+3y43z6dns6yglwQhAIRGMpjwN3++SGPVkNVeXDg+LgpHxR1IiLgdDkCmU6k0pH0PHM1OB9le1O6I12IButl+j0aUnwcIRPGRqKSzFSmN02Jxg3xnSIROAJLJDMp1PkSlU5KZCBZjxAHw5OO5415-L+wCF+Dl+XxfDANRAWPybNe1n0xC2ihAVDYbpUDOI5n5mFEHij-KdLrdD09nSjMbQm22PKgqvVwHJAB4WI8AB58UAqTrMAB8lOsLGpIa01j4AE84MAqPCdXT9SwjUn3tNZt9OcNRpaB587mCPkOfg6HPDzuax3sUUQFksVrKIwDpHiCUR1jMmvmWNWePWGXzgpgk0Y4GApAALc5K692G12hcI5eZtckAAjUgt3dBV92VKAjy8RpT3PBBLy0d87DvB9n1fM1iD4J97E6HCoCArdrUFYVQMwONXWNU0pCImEyOAZ0KKTEQ+nTHZLUg48YIZAti1LKoKwQOC4FrBDSCbVt207Wk9QZfReyncFZkwXRbFFSkJSwOBkjgMxt2CcjgwZIwwmAWJiJFRdxX-NEUg4PTHXo+MoAbUgjEqaoajM20SPnKADJIANVkjEQgA)

The expected result should be: when providing the generic type of `app`, the `data` should have its type correct.

Comment: are you okay to go without generics?

Comment: Your `finalData()` claims to return a `string` yet one of the return values is the `number` `data.age`.  I can try to fix your problem (generics don't work with control flow analysis, you can switch to unions of rest tuples instead) like [this playground link](https://tsplay.dev/mA2jXW) shows, but then I hit this `string`-vs-`number` issue.  Could you please [edit] to fix that?  Once you do so, does my suggestion meet your needs? If so I could write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: @wonderflame Thanks for asking. I did manage to solve this issue without generics; however, the `generics` way suits my logic to approach this kind of questions most, so I really want to dive deep into it. Appreciate your help.

Comment: @jcalz Thanks! I thought `generics` would be a perfect way to solve my problem as it is really easy to understand. If it is not able to do that, I am also very curious how the `unions of rest tuples` can handle the issue. Could you plz write up your answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently [generics](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) and `switch`/`case` [control flow analysis](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#control-flow-analysis) don't play nicely together in TypeScript.  The main reason is that there is that checking a *value* (like `app`) of a generic type (like `T`) can affect the apparent type of the value, but doesn't affect the generic type itself.  That's because if `app` is `App.AppOne`, it doesn't mean `T` must be `App.AppOne`.  It can still be the full [union type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) `App`:

```
finalData(
  Math.random() < 0.999 ? App.AppOne : App.AppTwo,
  mockedData[App.AppTwo]
); // no error
```

Oops, in the above, `T` is the union `App.AppOne | App.AppTwo`.  And that call is accepted by the compiler, but there's a 99.9% chance you are passing in `App.AppOne` for `app` while `data` is not the type you expected.  So the compiler complains for good reason.

You might say "hey, by `T extends App` I meant `T` should be *exactly one* of `App.AppOne` or `App.AppTwo`, not the union of both."  But right now there's no way to tell the compiler that.  There's a longstanding feature request for something like `T oneof App`, at [microsoft/TypeScript#27808](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/27808).  If that ever becomes possible, then maybe your code would suddenly work.  But for now we need a different approach.

---

Currently the support for `switch`/`case` control flow analysis is limited to situations where the value you are checking is the discriminant property of a [discriminated union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#discriminated-unions).

Luckily we can write `finalData()`'s call signature so that its pair of parameters is a [rest parameter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/rest_parameters) of a discriminated union [tuple type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-0.html#rest-parameters-with-tuple-types):

```
type FinalDataArgs = { [T in App]: [app: T, data: typeof mockedData[T]] }[App]
/* type FinalDataArgs = [app: App.AppOne, data: {
    readonly id: "1";
    readonly name: "app-one";
    readonly age: "18";
}] | [app: App.AppTwo, data: {
    readonly id: "2";
    readonly name: "app-two";
    readonly gender: "male";
}] */
```

That is implemented as a *distributive object type*, which is a [mapped type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html) into which we immediately [index](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/indexed-access-types.html) to get a union.  Each member of that union is a tuple type, corresponding to the desired parameters.

You can see that `FinalDataArgs` represents the two possibilities for how we'd like `finalData()` to be called.  It is *either* an argument list where the first argument is `App.AppOne` and the second argument is `typeof mockedData[App.AppOne]`, *or* an argument list where the first argument is `App.AppTwo` and the second argument is `typeof mockedData[App.AppTwo]`.  No possibility for mismatches there.  So `FinalDataArgs` is a discriminated union type.

---

When we write the call signature we can immediately [destructure](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) that rest parameter into the `app` and `data` parameters:

```
function finalData(...[app, data]: FinalDataArgs): string {
  if (app === App.AppOne) {
    return data.age // okay
  } else if (app === App.AppTwo) {
    return data.gender // okay
  } else {
    return 'no'
  }
}
```

And that works as desired because [TypeScript supports destructured discriminated unions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-6.html#control-flow-analysis-for-destructured-discriminated-unions).  It sees `app` and `data` as properties of the `FinalDataArgs` discriminated union, and thus `app` can be used to discriminate it.

And the problematic call from before is now prohibited, because it doesn't match one of the two acceptable tuple types for arguments:

```
finalData(
  Math.random() < 0.999 ? App.AppOne : App.AppTwo, // error!
  mockedData[App.AppTwo] // error!
);
```

The intended calls are still accepted:

```
finalData(App.AppOne, mockedData[App.AppOne]); // okay
finalData(App.AppTwo, mockedData[App.AppTwo]); // okay
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYOwrgtgBAggDnKBvAsAKCrBB5EwoC8UA5AIYIC0A9nsQDTqbxwAqA7lYSeXBQC4d66AL7p0AYxoBnPlAhVxAa2AATACKk+pLqgxQA2swB0zXMAC6ALmSNMUAJYrrxAIxC9mEKQjBnParQMHlCkAOa+JC4AHMS2wkGYhggmCOxUVjbBjs4ATO52UF4+fpQCVPl24SAqwABOzhCkADbAsXqiaMIhUlCSIDJiaEXAUnCk4vjYVHA9upgAZmAg4nz2NFDz9l5NGloAPCxQwAAefKAqPcwAfAAUPNYsdFAqmqTWfACecMBU83IKynUr30LHMAEprDJaltQpkCvY-ncEIQCERjKY8GC4QUoLVgHwwLUQM9XkYwsBbJgusAmlJ8AioEjEKi0clmGksXMcXiCUSSVojFUarVKVBqbT8FyCjzCcTiCByqKOlTbJttrtSDd0Tg8E95EpVBqknAUnAzOCANxQAD01qgVEUpA+qq2zQ1WrZqQ4eoBhuB2tYHEtNrtDqdgwWrp2rxuooAspoABZGWqkapUCA3LF7KAABiMAE4i1AAPxYE0Y-DWANpBJ2fWAo01oO2MFW22FTh1WpUWpPABGYD4RcLAFJeom0xN7X9tHAe-2WhARINPt8oAAxKMamC1UI9IhIAyHLbljL6e5QR78t5QNc-P4Nv1aEHmcxi43mdDWgBUUHQ96btury7vuXAXgg1aemauo3tYUq4sApAqDQTQfA4ThQAARC4WEWqKeLIah6HDNYWH+DQwB4QRSEoSAaEhOEZHRNRnTvgAPgYl7NlQTwvFo8E0UR9Hodk2E5Kx0q0cRhTeBE5GlBwkl2IRdEMUKdRkY0LSscI74-ta6CLMsqzrGqboxkYVkQXAfGvBkW7qiBe5SBCUBQjC2IMkyKKshWOrAJyNG8sS-GkGS4RxEcEoOIiPC+eWpoctimAynyYWCucdRRTSdIpYhIUkAqbQqp0gzmdGWgev5MHAD6BpAi+Abmm2Ib2o6zpoBV7o8fVjb+tBaTBh2YadUZwFVbYCZ8Mmqbppm2Z5oWxZls1eBQFBNW1m13a9gAhLYT6NaQxpJUGO21D2tQHWgrXoEAA)